# how to make a JTextArea have clickable buttons

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

As the title says I'm trying to make it so my `JTextArea` have some strings so that I can call other functions, like a hyperlink of sorts, can that be done?

For reference, I would like to know how the left side of any Tutorialspoint tutorial is made but in Java.

PS: I'm using a `CardLayout`.

EDIT: [Something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78lB1.png)

Comment: A link, a screenshot..would be nice . I personally don't see what looks like a `JTextArea` with buttons on this site.

Comment: you might start with the free online tutorial to learn what's possible: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/

Comment: i didnt know i could put a link in here, tried it in the past and it was blocked..
Gonna edit post.

Comment: A text area is for plain text (no components etc.). A `JEditorPane` or `JTextPane` support styled text (including links and buttons.

Comment: Your link doesn't look like a `JTextArea` but a `JList`

Comment: @MadProgrammer i know,i'm not trying to copy that design, i'm just trying to put some strings in there and when i click them, they call other functions

Comment: *"I would like to know how the left side of.."* Having said that, for a group of links (or buttons) down the left, I'd recommend using a `JList` (as mentioned by @MadProgrammer) in the `LINE_START` of a `BorderLayout`, with the `JTextArea` in the `CENTER`.

Comment: @F.Dinis *"i know,i'm not trying to copy that design, i'm just trying to put some strings in there and when i click them, they call other functions"* - Then start with [How to use JList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html)

Comment: Humm ok thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget about using a `JTextArea`. Take a look at [**`JList`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html) instead. This is Swing's basic list class. It supports the selection of one or more items from a list. Although often the list consists of strings, it is possible to create a list of just about any object that can be displayed.

Although a **JList** will work properly by itself, most of the time  you  will wrap a **JList** inside a [**`JScrollPane`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html), so long lists will automatically be scrollable.

---

A **JList** generates a [**`ListSelectionEvent`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/ListSelectionEvent.html) when the user makes or changes a selection. This event is also generated when the user deselects a n item. It is handled by implementing [**`ListSelectionListener`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/ListSelectionListener.html). This listener specifies only one method,  which is called:

```
void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent le)
```

Here, *le* is a reference to the object that generated the event. Although **ListSelectionEvent** does provide  some methods of its own, often you will interrogate the **JList** object itself to determine what has occurred.

---

By default, a **JList** allows the user to select multiple ranges of items within the list, but you can change this behavior by calling **`setSelectionMode(int)`**, which is defined by **JList**. The integer passed to this method must be one of the values defined by the **ListSelectionModel** interface:

```
SINGLE_SELECTION
SINGLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION
MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION
```

You can obtain the selected values by calling [`getSelectedValuesList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#getSelectedValuesList()), or,  if you are using single selection, you can call [`getSelectedValue()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#getSelectedValue()). Once you have the selected the value(s), you can invoke the method(s) dedicated to that/those objects accordingly.

---

One last tip: In Java, they are called methods, not functions ;)

Happy programming!